# Let's Encrypt via certbot on Shared Linux Server

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

Trying to install an SSL certificate on my shared hosting (Linux/cPanel at JustHost) server using Let's Encrypt. It's running Apache CentOS 6.4.

I do have SSH access so used the certbot. It downloaded to the server but I couldn't run it.

Looks like there are various manual options.

Wondering if anyone got one of these manual options or certbot to run on justhost.

I'm using a shared server so issue may be that I don't have root access.

Comment: Have you tried using certbot's [webroot option](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#webroot)? It can be done without root access, and essentially just places a few files under `.well-known` on your web root directory to verify your domain.

Comment: Needs more detail; not sure how you're trying to use certbot, and the permissions you have on a 'justhost' server. In general, you won't need root access, but not all function will be available to you. If you don't have root access, are you able to use the certificate?

Comment: So, it's not necessarily for a JustHost server - for any CPanel-based shared Linux server. CLI access is a jail shell, so unsure if certbot can even be run.  Is acme.sh (and *manual* re-running / insertion of the completed certificates) the only option, or is there a way to automate the SSL certificate renewal process on a shared hosting CPanel account?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you aren't really able to run your own commands on the remote server but have got the FTP account to upload files to the server and a limited SSH/SCP access to e.g. reload the HTTP server after the certificates were updated.

If this is true, you might wish to use [`getssl`](https://github.com/srvrco/getssl) instead of `certbot`. `getssl` allows using an FTP server as a destination to place ACME challenges. The [README](https://github.com/srvrco/getssl#readme) for the project is really well written and pretty much covers it all, but to get a rough idea on how it would work: for your Web site (let's say it's http://example.com/) you'll need to create a file `~/.getssl/example.com/getssl.cfg` with the following contents:

```
PRIVATE_KEY_ALG="rsa"

# Acme Challenge Location.
# If these start with ftp: then the next variables are ftpuserid:ftppassword:servername:ACL_location
ACL=('ftp:ftpuserid:ftppassword:${DOMAIN}:/web/.well-known/acme-challenge')

# Location for all your certs
DOMAIN_CERT_LOCATION="ssh:sshuserid@server5:/etc/ssl/domain.crt"
DOMAIN_KEY_LOCATION="ssh:sshuserid@server5:/etc/ssl/domain.key"

# The command needed to reload apache / nginx or whatever you use.
RELOAD_CMD="ssh:sshuserid@server5:service apache2 reload"
```